# What does the "tank stock" mean here in the news title?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage

"Did Donald Trump tank Boeing's stock because he was mad about a news article? " Please let me know if you know what "tank stock" means here!

Answer (score 1):

It's in the dictionary (MW, intransitive verb, definition 2)

[tank](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tank)

> to suffer rapid decline, failure, or collapse "bought a stock that quickly tanked"

(although in this case it's used as a transitive verb, in a slang usage particular to investing)